# Fire an event when the mouse moves off the page?

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener, mouseout

I want to fire an action to dataLayer if the mouse moves off the page. I'm assuming adding an event listener would work and passing in 'mouseout' but needed some help setting it up as I am new to javascript. Thank you !

Comment: please confirm me. Is page document.body?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your use-case here ? There are quite a few ways to achieve the above. Also what does your code look like ? Please include the code as well If you have any. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like:

```js
    document.addEventListener("mouseleave", (event) => {
        if (event.clientY <= 0 || event.clientX <= 0 || (event.clientX >= window.innerWidth || event.clientY >= window.innerHeight)) {
            /* do what you have to do here */ 
        }
    });
```

Following Luke McCrea, I made the test with the following:

```js
    document.addEventListener("mouseleave", (event) => {
        /* do what you have to do here */ 
        }
    });
```

Seems to work same.
It was a quick on a blank HTML page, with nothing else loaded. But no real reason it's not working on real big project.

Comment: Is there a need for the if statement in the event listener?

Comment: @luke if out do something, that's the only need of this statement

Comment: @pierfarrugia can you explain clientY, clientX, innerWidth and innerHeight? is this to specify that it's going off the actual page?

Comment: @pierfarrugia Is there a need for it though? doesn't the event listener work fine without it?

Comment: @luke seems you are right, I just made the test. quick test, it's working same

Comment: @SuperSako22 for event.client see here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_clientx.asp, for inner check here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth